# How to offset the nth child of an element

Tags: html, css

I am trying to extract the nth child of an element, so that elements appear stacked within the same container.

I've tried reading over https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child, but to no avail.

I recreated the problem in a jsfiddle,

https://jsfiddle.net/ndga732y/

html:

```
<table>
  <td>
    <p id="image-1">first content</p>
    <p id="image-2">second content</p>
  </td>
</table>
```

css:

```
p:nth-child(0n){
  offset-x: n*2px;
  offset-y: n*2px;
}
```

I understand that selecting the nth child is easy, using the nth-child selector, but how do I use the n-value to create a different offset, depending on its order in a container?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post an example of the code you've been working on?

Answer (score 5):

This isn't possible with plain CSS unfortunately.

You can use Javascript or a CSS preprocessor (probably a postprocessor as well?).

Here is how I would approach it with Sass, which would compile to CSS:

```
@for $i from 1 through 2 {
  p:nth-child(#{$i}) {
    top: $i * 100px;
    left: $i * 50px;
    position: relative;
  }  
}
```

and here's a quick demo: http://www.sassmeister.com/gist/8af65851d1c404be698f

Answer (score 1):

You could use padding left and do something like

```css
p:nth-child(2){
 padding-left: 50px;
}
```